# Problems with IPv6 connect in C

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, berkeley-sockets

I'm trying to code an agnostic echo server, that could accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connection. I'm working with addrinfo structure, set with getaddrinfo.
Ipv4 connect has no problem while I can't get a working ipV6 connection.
I think my problem could be due to a wrong getaddrinfo parameter, but I'm not able to see where I'm going wrong.
Here's my code
client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      int simpleSocket = 0, simplePort = 0,returnStatus = 0, n; 
      char buffer[1024] = "";
      struct hostent *hostinfo;
      struct addrinfo simpleServer, *res;

      if (3 != argc) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
          exit(1);
      }

      simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);    

      memset(&simpleServer, 0, sizeof simpleServer);
      simpleServer.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
      simpleServer.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
      simpleServer.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

      returnStatus = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &simpleServer, &res);

      simpleSocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

      char *s = NULL;
      switch(res->ai_addr->sa_family) {
      case AF_INET: {
            struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res;
            s = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), s, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
            break;
      }
      case AF_INET6: {
            struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res;
            s = malloc(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
            break;
      }
      default:
            break;
      }
      fprintf(stdout, "IP address: %s\n", s);

      returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
      fprintf(stdout, "Type a message \n");

      memset(buffer, '\0', strlen(buffer));
      fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
      returnStatus = write(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

      memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
      fprintf(stdout, "Waiting server..\n");     
      returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

      fprintf(stdout, "Message: %s\n", buffer);

      close(simpleSocket);
      return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      int simpleSocket = 0, simplePort = 0, returnStatus = 0, check = 1, n; 
      char buffer[1024];

      struct addrinfo simpleServer, *res;

      if (2 != argc) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
          exit(1);
      }

      simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

      memset(&simpleServer, 0, sizeof simpleServer);
      simpleServer.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
      simpleServer.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
      simpleServer.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

      getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &simpleServer, &res);

      simpleSocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
      returnStatus =bind(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
      returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

      struct addrinfo clientName = { 0 };
      int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);
      int simpleChildSocket = 0;

      while (1) {
         while (1) { 
            simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

            fprintf(stdout,"Waiting..\n");

            memset(&buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));        
            returnStatus = read(simpleChildSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            fprintf(stdout, "Message: %s\n", buffer);

            write(simpleChildSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));     
         }
      }
      close(simpleChildSocket);
      close(simpleSocket);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop nested inside an infinite loop?

Comment: As for your problem, in the server you use the first entry returned by the `getaddrinfo` to create the socket and bind to an interface. If you want to accept connections using both IPv4 and IPv6 you need *two* sockets, and bind one to an IPv4 address and the other to an IPv6 address.

Comment: Oh, and you need to set `clientNameLength` before every call to `accept`, as it may modify the argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg On some systems a socket bound to :: can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

Comment: How exactly do you start server and client? What output do you get? From what do you deduce that it failed?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: "*you need two sockets, and bind one to an IPv4 address and the other to an IPv6 address*" - on platforms that support **dual-stack** sockets, you can accept **both** IPv4 and IPv6 clients on the same listening socket. Create a single IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) socket and use `setsockopt()` to disable its `IPV6_V6ONLY` option before calling `bind()`. The client IP address reported by `accept()` will tell you whether the client is IPv4 or IPv6, so be sure your receiving `addr` buffer is large enough to hold `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr_in6`. Best to use `sockaddr_storage` as the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JoachimPileborg mentioned in comments, the problem is that your server code is not opening listening sockets for every address that `getaddrinfo()` gives you.  You are specifying `AF_UNSPEC` in your `simpleServer` struct, so `getaddrinfo()` will give you a list of *both* IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. You are creating a listening socket for only the first entry in that list, which happens to be an IPv4 address.  That is why your IPv4 client succeeds and your IPv6 client fails.  You need to loop through the list creating a separate listening socket for each entry.

You are also making other mistakes, like not resetting your `clientNameLength` variable each time you call `accept()`, using `addrinfo` as your  `clientName` buffer when you should be using `sockaddr_storage` instead, and not paying attention to the return value of `read()`.

Try something more like this:

```
include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MAX_SERVERS 10
#define MAX_CLIENTS 50
#define MAX_SOCKETS (MAX_SERVERS + MAX_CLIENTS)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    int simpleSocket, simplePort, returnStatus, n, m; 
    char buffer[1024];
    pollfd simpleSockets[MAX_SOCKETS];
    int numSockets = 0, numServers = 0;

    struct addrinfo simpleServer, *res, *addr;

    if (2 != argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    memset(&simpleServer, 0, sizeof simpleServer);
    simpleServer.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 and/or IPv6, whatever is available
    simpleServer.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    simpleServer.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

    if (0 != getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &simpleServer, &res))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    addr = res;
    while (NULL != addr)
    {
        simpleSocket = socket(res->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
        if (-1 == simpleSocket)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "socket failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
            if (0 == returnStatus)
                returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

            if (0 == returnStatus)
            {
                simpleSockets[numSockets].fd = simpleSocket;
                simpleSockets[numSockets].events = POLLIN;
                simpleSockets[numSockets].revents = 0;
                ++numSockets;
                ++numServers;
                if (MAX_SERVERS == numServers)
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "bind/listen failed\n");
                close(simpleSocket);
            }
        }
        addr = addr->next;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    if (0 == numServers)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no servers are listening\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_storage clientName;
    int clientNameLength;

    while (1)
    { 
        returnStatus = poll(simpleSockets, numSockets, -1);
        if (-1 == returnStatus)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "poll failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (0 == returnStatus)
            continue;

        for (n = 0; n < numSockets; ++n)
        {
            if (simpleSockets[n].revents & POLLIN)
            {
                if (n < numServers)
                {
                    clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

                    simpleSocket = accept(simpleSockets[n].fd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);
                    if (-1 == simpleSocket)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "accept failed\n");
                        continue;
                    }

                    for (m = numServers; m < numSockets; ++m)
                    {
                        if (-1 == simpleSockets[m].fd)
                        {
                            simpleSockets[m].fd = simpleSocket;
                            simpleSockets[m].events = POLLIN;
                            simpleSockets[m].revents = 0;
                            simpleSocket = -1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((-1 != simpleSocket) && (MAX_SOCKETS > numSockets))
                    {
                        simpleSockets[numSockets].fd = simpleSocket;
                        simpleSockets[numSockets].events = POLLIN;
                        simpleSockets[numSockets].revents = 0;
                        ++numSockets;
                        simpleSocket = -1;
                    }

                    if (-1 != simpleSocket)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Too many clients connected\n");
                        close(simpleSocket);
                    }
                    else
                        fprintf(stdout, "Client connected\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    returnStatus = read(simpleSockets[n].fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    if (0 >= returnStatus)
                    {
                        if (0 > returnStatus)
                            fprintf(stdout, "Client error, disconnecting\n");
                        else
                            fprintf(stdout, "Client disconnected\n");

                        close(simpleSockets[n].fd);
                        simpleSockets[n].fd = -1;
                        simpleSockets[n].events = 0;
                        simpleSockets[n].revents = 0;

                        continue;
                    }

                    fprintf(stdout, "Message: %.*s\n", returnStatus, buffer);
                    write(simpleSockets[n].fd, buffer, returnStatus);     
                }
            }

            if (simpleSockets[n].revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP|POLLNVAL))
            {
                if (simpleSockets[n].revents & POLLHUP)
                    fprintf(stdout, "Client disconnected\n");
                else if (n >= numServers)
                    fprintf(stdout, "Client error, disconnecting\n");
                else
                    fprintf(stdout, "Server error, closing\n");

                close(simpleSockets[n].fd);
                simpleSockets[n].fd = -1;
                simpleSockets[n].events = 0;
                simpleSockets[n].revents = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (n = 0; n < numSockets; ++n)
    {
        if (-1 != simpleSockets[n].fd)
            close(simpleSockets[n].fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With that said, if you are running on a platform that supports **dual-stack** sockets, your server does not have to create any IPv4 listening sockets at all.  It can create IPv6 sockets only, and then disable their `IPV6_V6ONLY` option.  This will allow them to accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients.  The client address returned by `accept()` will tell you whether an IPv4 or IPv6 client has connected.

```
memset(&simpleServer, 0, sizeof simpleServer);
simpleServer.ai_family = AF_INET6;
simpleServer.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
simpleServer.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

if (0 != getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &simpleServer, &res))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

addr = res;
while (NULL != addr)
{
    simpleSocket = socket(res->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
    if (-1 == simpleSocket)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket failed\n");
    }
    else
    {
        n = 0;
        returnStatus = setsockopt(simpleSocket, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &n, sizeof(n));
        ...
    }
    addr = addr->next;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

the client.c code is flawed, it's storing the complete addrinfo in sockaddr_in structure.
res is of type `addrinfo` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)

```
struct addrinfo {
   int              ai_flags;
   int              ai_family;
   int              ai_socktype;
   int              ai_protocol;
   socklen_t        ai_addrlen;
   struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
   char            *ai_canonname;
   struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};
```

so instead of
`struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res;`
it should be
`struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;`

like

```
case AF_INET: {
    struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)res->ai_addr;
    s = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr_in->sin_addr), s, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    break;
  }
  case AF_INET6: {
    struct sockaddr_in6 *addr_in6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr;
    s = malloc(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(addr_in6->sin6_addr), s, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    break;
  }
```

after this modification the code works as expected.